# I need help with finding commuting data for an O.R. MSc thesis

Tags: online-resources, data

I'm working on my MSc thesis and I need real commuting to work data to apply to the optimization models I developed. I read multiple papers that use commuting data and they all refer to public statistics. I tried to find this data for multiple countries (23 countries so far) but I can't seem to find it at all. Can anyone guide me on how I can proceed, and if there's a way to access data from papers?

Thank you,

Comment: For some journals there's usually a data sharing statement like "Data available on request from corresponding author" at <insert email address>. So if you can't find it online you can try asking them (politely) for the data.

Comment: You might want to specify what sort of data you need (head count, travel time, routing) and whether you are including people who ride trains (and, if so, whether subways count), people who use other mass transit (buses), or just people who drive an automobile.

Comment: If you know german, this might be in the vein of what you are looking for: https://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset/passagierzahlung-s-bahn-hamburg https://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset/data-s-bahn-stuttgart-ris-archiv-daten